# Access VBA to Update Table Record

Tags: vba, ms-access, button

I am trying to assign code to a button in MS Access that will update a table record. When the button is clicked, I'd like it to reference a user-updated item number in a nearby list box (List26), lookup that matching item number field in a table (Assets), and change a field (Owner) on that record to be blank.

I have been digging around and found some logic around the DAO Recordset but I am not familiar with VBA enough to get it setup correctly or know if this is the right path. Below is what I've gotten to so far:

```
Private Sub Check_In_Device_Click()
    Dim rec As DAO.Recordset

'Table1 called "Assets"
    Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Assets")
    
'if the data in List26 matches an Item# in Asset table...
    If [Item].value = [List26].value Then
    rec.MoveFirst
    rec.Edit
'change Owner field to null
    rec![Owner].value = ""
    rec.Update
    rec.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Item* is probably numeric, and use *Null* to blank a field, thus try:

```vb
Private Sub Check_In_Device_Click()

    Dim rec As DAO.Recordset

    ' Table1 called "Assets"
    Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Assets")

    If rec.RecordCount > 0 Then    
        ' If the data in List26 matches an Item# in Asset table...
        rec.MoveFirst
        rec.FindFirst "Item = '" & Me!List26.Value & "'"
        If Not rec.NoMatch Then
            ' Item found.
            rec.Edit
            ' Change Owner field to null
            rec!Owner.Value = Null
            rec.Update
        End If
    End If
    rec.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! The "Item" field is set to text still but using NULL got it to pass.

Comment: OK, changed that. So the answer is?

Answer (score 0):

`OpenRecordset` take a table/query name and a type, you will need to open as dbOpenDynaset to use `.findfirst`

Make sure your listbox is set up to return the correct value using the `Bound Column` property (the default will probably be the unique key of the record).

Something like this should do it:

```
Private Sub Check_In_Device_Click()
    Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
    
    Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Assets", dbOpenDynaset)
    
    With rec
        .FindFirst "[Item] Like '" & List26.Value & "'"
        .Edit
        ![Owner] = ""
        .Update
        .Close
    End With
    
End Sub
```

If you want to loop through the entire recordset you can use:

```
    Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
    
    Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Assets", dbOpenDynaset)
    
    With rec
        .MoveFirst
        Do Until .EOF
            If ![Item] Like List26.Value Then
                .Edit
                ![Owner].value = Null
                .Update
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you! This cleaned it up quite a bit and gave me a much better response when debugging. Still ended up getting a data conversation error against the ![Owner] field, but a switch to NULL and it's good to go now.